# How do I skip a music video on the Apple TV (4th gen)?

Tags: music, appletv

When listening to my music on random on the Apple TV sometimes a music video pops up that I want to skip. Clicking on the right side of the Siri remote skips forwards a few seconds instead of the skipping the entire video. Is there an easy way to skip the entire video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported on ATV4, although I thought it was on earlier versions.  I even tried a programmable remote (a Harmony), which offers more buttons/commands than the Apple remote, but none of them seem to offer a Skip/Next function during music videos.